# Go write unix /tmp/mysql.sock: broken pipe when sending a lot of requests

Tags: mysql, go

I have a Go API endpoint that makes several MySQL query. When the endpoint receives a small number of requests, it works just fine. However, I am now testing it using apache bench with 100 requests. The first 100 all went through. However, the 2nd 100 caused this error to appear

```
    2014/01/15 12:08:03 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:58602: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 973 [running]:
net/http.func·009()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1093 +0xae
runtime.panic(0x402960, 0x9cf419)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 +0x106
database/sql.(*Rows).Close(0x0, 0xc2107af540, 0x69)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/database/sql/sql.go:1576 +0x1e
store.findProductByQuery(0xc2107af540, 0x69, 0x0, 0xb88e80, 0xc21000ac70)
    /Users/dennis.suratna/workspace/session-go/src/store/product.go:83 +0xe3
store.FindProductByAppKey(0xc210337748, 0x7, 0x496960, 0x6, 0xc2105eb1b0)
    /Users/dennis.suratna/workspace/session-go/src/store/product.go:28 +0x11c
api.SessionHandler(0xb9eff8, 0xc2108ee200, 0xc2108f5750, 0xc2103285a0, 0x0, ...)
    /Users/dennis.suratna/workspace/session-go/src/api/session_handler.go:31 +0x2fb
api.func·001(0xb9eff8, 0xc2108ee200, 0xc2108f5750, 0xc2103285a0)
    /Users/dennis.suratna/workspace/session-go/src/api/api.go:81 +0x4f
reflect.Value.call(0x3ad9a0, 0xc2101ffdb0, 0x130, 0x48d520, 0x4, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:474 +0xe0b
reflect.Value.Call(0x3ad9a0, 0xc2101ffdb0, 0x130, 0xc2103c4a00, 0x3, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.2/libexec/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:345 +0x9d
github.com/codegangsta/inject.(*injector).Invoke(0xc2103379c0, 0x3ad9a0, 0xc2101ffdb0, 0x4311a0, 0x1db94e, ...)
```

It looks like it's not caused by the number of concurrent requests but, rather, something that is not properly closed. I am already closing every prepare statement that I create in my code. I am wondering if anyone has ever seen this before.

Edit:
This is how I am initializing my MySQL connection:

```
func InitStore(environment string) error {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connStr(environment))
    ....

    S = &Store{
        Mysql:       db,
        Environment: environment,
   }
}
```

In this happens only once when I start the server.

Comment: Looks like your MySQL's maximum number of connection has exceeded or something like that. And the panic is because you are not checking some error when connecting to it.

Comment: Well yea I am trying to figure what is the right way to manage these connections. I am doing one time of `sql.Open` when the server starts. All other queries and prepared statements are called using the DB instance return from that call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I was able to solve this problem and now I can send ~500 requests with 10 concurrency with no more `Broken pipe` or `Too many connections error`.

I think it all comes down to following best practices. When you don't expect multiple rows to be returned user `QueryRow` instead of `Query` AND chain it with `Scan`

```
db.QueryRow(...).Scan(...)
```

If you don't expect rows to be returned and if you're not going to re-use your statements, use `Exec` not `Prepare`.

If you have prepared statement or querying multiple rows. Don't forget to `Close()`

Got all of the above from

https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/111

Comment: Another thing: When you are using `QueryRow` make sure to handle the `sql.ErrNoRows` error when nothing is found.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Go 1.2.x you can use [db.SetMaxOpenConns](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxOpenConns) to tell the sql package to not open more than X connections. Queries that need a database connection after X connections are already open (and busy) will block until there's an available connection.

That being said: what are the next lines of the "stack trace"?  Line ~1093 in http/server.go is the recover code when your serve function fails. It looks more like you are just mishandling some data and that makes it fail or you are missing an error check and then try processing data when you really were returned an error, etc.

Comment: updated the stack trace. I don't think I am mishandling data because I am just posting the same request for 100 times. The first 100 goes through just fine but one of the next 100 requests gives me that error. This is consistent and after the first one breaks, any other request that requires MySQL connection would give me the same error.